# nginx на ubuntu 16.04 server выдаёт 404 Not Found

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, http-status-code-404

Установил на Ubuntu 16.04 server, apache2. при переходе на сайт выдаётся 404 ошибка.

Виртуальные хосты настроил.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #Имя хоста
    ServerName webinar.implant.ru
    #Корневая папка хоста
    DocumentRoot /var/www/bigbluebutton-default
    <Directory /var/www/bigbluebutton-default>
        #Разрешение на перезапись всех директив при помощи .htaccess
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Вот файл nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
client_max_body_size 100m;
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type text/html;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }


    #mail {
    #       # See sample authentication script at:
    #       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
    #
    #       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
    #       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
    #       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
    #
    #       server {
    #               listen     localhost:110;
    #               protocol   pop3;
    #               proxy      on;
    #       }
    #
    #       server {
    #               listen     localhost:143;
    #               protocol   imap;
    #               proxy      on;
    #       }
    #}
```

Если нужна еще информация, я быстро предоставлю.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: эээ... так у вас кто по итогу за главного? nginx или Apache? Что-то я запутался...

Comment: @de_frag, apache у меня за главного , еще у меня в логах вот такая строчка  2018/05/16 10:44:08 [error] 1092#1092: *2100 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.12.40.194, server: webinar.implant.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:81/index.php", host: "webinar.implant.ru"

Comment: @de_frag если я правильно понял, запрос перенаправляется в 127.0.0.1/index.php, а у меня индекс лежит в /var/www/site

Comment: @de_frag как это поправить?

Comment: Ваш `bigbluebutton` хочет коннекта на 127.0.0.1:81, другими словами на локалхосте должен кто-то (nginx?) слушать на 81-м порту. А у вас `Connection refused`. Проверьте, есть ли (запущен ли) слушатель на 81-м порту.

Comment: @de_frag а как это проверить, и добавить если нет?

Comment: Проверить:  `netstat -tan| grep 81` должно появиться что-то типа: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:81`. А добавить, тут уж возможны варианты. Для этого нужно понимать, что и зачем добавлять в зависимости от схемы/инфраструктуры приложения. Возможно достаточно будет заставить nginx слушать 81-й порт. Например, директива `server { listen 81; }`. А может быть это должен делать Апач...